# Debug of recursive algorithm (big data size)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I use DFS based algorithm for computing strong components in the large graph. The algorithm works fine on small graphs, but i encounter with a problem on the large graphs. So after around 28 K recursive calls of DFS function program just hangs. VS2010 give me an message VS is busy, no crashes no errors. To figure out what is going on, i printed some information (can't run it in debug because of the low speed). And i found out that program hangs on position 4 and dosen't reaches position 1 (watch the code).

```
// Main DFS function
void DFS(vector<Edge>& graph, int source_node, bool *vertex_visited, pair<int, int>& direction){

    cout << "\r" << "Position 1" << std::flush;
    // mark vertex as visited
    vertex_visited[source_node - 1] = false;
    // array for all neighbour edges 
    vector<vector<Edge>::iterator> all_neighbours;

    // doesent matter 
    if (direction.second){
        size_of_scc++;
    }

    // binary search of edges incident with source vertex
    pair<vector<Edge>::iterator, bool> itera = find_if_binary_for_edges(graph.begin(), graph.end(), source_node);
    cout << "\r" << "Position 2" << std::flush;

    // push all incident edges to all_neighbours vector
    if (itera.second){
        pair<vector<Edge>::iterator, vector<Edge>::iterator> bounds = find_all_in_range(itera.first, graph);
        vector<Edge>::iterator it = bounds.first;
        while (it != bounds.second){
            all_neighbours.push_back(it++);
        }
    }

    cout << "\r" << "Position 3" << std::flush;

    // if this vertex wasn't visited in the past cal DFS from neighbour vertex
    for (vector<vector<Edge>::iterator>::iterator it = all_neighbours.begin(); it != all_neighbours.end(); ++it){
        if (vertex_visited[(**it)[1] - 1]){
            cout << "\r" << "Position 4" << std::flush;
            DFS(graph, (**it)[1], vertex_visited, direction);
        };
    }

    // need this stuff for SCC computation
    cout << "\r" << "Position 5" << std::flush;
    if (direction.first)
        finishing_times[finishing_times_counter++] = source_node;
}
```

So i don't know what to do next, which debug steps i need to do next ...? After position 4 program have to call DFS again and then print "Position 1" but it dosen't happens. Because of what it could be? Graph have approximately 857K vertexes and 5 * 10^6 edges. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you get a stack overflow, due to too many recursive calls.

Comment: So why i don't get stack overflow error??

Comment: Stackoverflow usually causes a distinctive crash, but not guaranteed I suppose [it's UB after all].

Comment: I take that that's not "done" and spending quite some time "getting back"?

Comment: If you know you will be doing 28k (sic!) recursive calls, I'd just change the algorithm to iterative version.

Comment: I would print the stackpointer somewhere during the recursive calls [perhaps at all positions - just create  a temp variable, and print the address of it].

Comment: seems that 3 arguments (of four) could be placed outside. Make an overload receiving only `int source_node`, see if the num of recursion allowed change

Comment: @MatsPetersson what can i get from it?

Comment: It would at the very least tell you how much stack you are using. Compare that to how much stack you nomially have, and it should tell you whether that is part of the problem or not.

Comment: @CapelliC i removed one argument from DFS, number of recursive calls remained the same but now i get stackoverlow error, so that is the problem. But i wonder why i didn't get it earlier ...

Comment: Any reason why you are implementing this recursively? The 'standard' implementation of a DFS, using `std::stack`, is clearer (imo) and doesn't suffer from stack overflow problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that was stackoverflow error, i didn't get it at the first time, but after removing some arguments from DFS list, i encountered stackoverflowerror.

Comment: What did you do eventually to fix the stackoverflow error? I'm trying to code up a similar algorithm for DFS on a large graph and I suspect I'm running into similar issue.